# Wordpress redirect to directory with Runcloud

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have my own Wordpress website hosted on Vultr and managed with Runcloud. I created another Web application for another wordpress website.

My goal is to host this second Wordpress website on https://domain/myfolder.

I used to do it by adding the Wordpress install in a folder in my root folder but Runcloud does not work like this. You have a runcloud folder with a folder for each web application.

I am able to redirect subdomain.domain.com to https://domain/myfolder but then I get a 404 error...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just create a new web application for your subdomain. A folder for the web application will be auto created.

In runcloud, each site (subdomain included) has its own folder.